# Extract heart rate code in swift using iwatch

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

Im using the below code to extract heart rate, but when i use it inside my custom class , it says that self.heartRateQuery is not defined inside the class.and its correct coz in my class there is no heartRateQuery. Im new to swift. can you please tell how to deal with this ? i just want to extract the heartrate. so what correction should i do in the code and where to put the code below.inside my interface controller?

```
  // Creating the sample for the heart rate
  guard let sampleType: HKSampleType =
    HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate) else {
      return
  }

  /// Creating an observer, so updates are received whenever HealthKit’s
  // heart rate data changes.
  self.heartRateQuery = HKObserverQuery.init(
    sampleType: sampleType,
    predicate: nil) { [weak self] _, _, error in
      guard error == nil else {
        log.warn(error!)
        return
      }

      /// When the completion is called, an other query is executed
      /// to fetch the latest heart rate
      self.fetchLatestHeartRateSample(completion: { sample in
        guard let sample = sample else {
          return
        }

        /// The completion in called on a background thread, but we
        /// need to update the UI on the main.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

          /// Converting the heart rate to bpm
          let heartRateUnit = HKUnit(from: "count/min")
          let heartRate = sample
            .quantity
            .doubleValue(for: heartRateUnit)

          /// Updating the UI with the retrieved value
          self?.heartRateLabel.setText("\(Int(heartRate))")
        }
      })
  }
}

public func fetchLatestHeartRateSample(
  completion: @escaping (_ sample: HKQuantitySample?) -> Void) {

  /// Create sample type for the heart rate
  guard let sampleType = HKObjectType
    .quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate) else {
      completion(nil)
    return
  }

  /// Predicate for specifiying start and end dates for the query
  let predicate = HKQuery
    .predicateForSamples(
      withStart: Date.distantPast,
      end: Date(),
      options: .strictEndDate)

  /// Set sorting by date.
  let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(
    key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate,
    ascending: false)

  /// Create the query
  let query = HKSampleQuery(
    sampleType: sampleType,
    predicate: predicate,
    limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit),
    sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (_, results, error) in

      guard error == nil else {
        print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        return
      }

      completion(results?[0] as? HKQuantitySample)
  }

  self.healthStore.execute(query)
}~
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you instantiate the heartRateQuery object as a property of your custom class? So:

```swift
class MyCustomClass: SomeSuperClass, SomeProtocols {
    var heartRateQuery: HKObserverQuery()?

    [YOUR CODE HERE]

}
```